# positioning commandbutton fail

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Any idea how to center the icon or inline the icon display in p:column like using text-allign:center or display:inline ? Below is the code example

```
 <P:column>
 <h:outputText value="#{name}"> </h:outputText>
<p:commandButton value="" icon="ui-icon-edit"  style="background-color:transparent !important; border:0px none;"/> 
</p:column>
```

Is there any way to at least inline the icon with outputtext, So that this edit icon is inline with outputtext ? i have try this

```
style="display:inline"
```

but no luck

am using primefaces 3.5

Comment: Check if you're using a theme and try the 'hard' way, trying directly on browser developer tool, look [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=19312) for some help/example

Comment: This is initially all plain html and css. 100% not jsf related and only very slightly PrimeFaces. But you need the client-side html